# What is the font family of the close/minimize/reduce button in Windows 10?

Tags: wpf, fonts

We are developing a custom header bar and we need to use the close/minimize/reduce button from the Windows 10 theme even if we are in windows 7.

Our approach was to use the font family from Windows 10. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: It's [Segoe MDL2 Assets](http://modernicons.io/segoe-mdl2/cheatsheet/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to download the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font family from here or just copy the .ttf file over from a Windows 10 instance: https://www.azfonts.net/families/segoe-mdl2-assets.html

Once you have done this, you should add the .ttf file to your project as a resource. You can then use the symbols like this:

```
<!-- Minimize -->
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE949;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />

<!-- Maximize -->
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE739;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />

<!-- Restore -->
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE923;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />

<!-- Close -->
<TextBlock Text="Value="&#xE106;" FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/#Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" />
```

Comment: You can simply use FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"

Comment: Very skinny chances FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" will resolve on non-Windows 10 PC's. If this concerns you I suggest to embed font in assembly as per accepted answer.

Comment: Has anyone actually tried using this code and can confirm that it works? Because that syntax is wrong...