# WPF: How to make native windows control button with custom window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I had to change the color and icon of the title bar, so I used custom window. But in this way, I have to create my own window control buttons(minimize, maximize, restore, close). I want to use the native ones like the thing that Microsoft Office and Google Chrome did. How should I do?

**Office**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

Comment: I did this a few years ago in WPF. IIRC the icons Windows uses are just characters in the Wingdings font (I think). If you run `charmap` and look at the various symbol fonts hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: But there is no symbol like the restore button.(Two squares, one covers another one.) How did chrome make it?

Comment: Depends on the options available on the custom control... you could alter the controls code but more than likely they already coded some parameter to toggle from your side - whats the name of the library?

Comment: I did this for work, and I'm off this week. When I get back in to the office, I'll try to remember to look up how I did it and let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to just use the default chrome buttons as-is in a custom window I am afraid.

But you could quite easily create your own ones using the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font:

[What is the font family of the close/minimize/reduce button in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770531/what-is-the-font-family-of-the-close-minimize-reduce-button-in-windows-10/44777463#44777463)

[Show default window buttons on WPF Window using WindowChrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190041/show-default-window-buttons-on-wpf-window-using-windowchrome/44199807#44199807)

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thank you!