# How to show default buttons on WPF customized title bar using WindowChrome

Tags: wpf, xaml, window-chrome

I'm following the article [Restyle Your Window](https://www.eidias.com/blog/2014/1/27/restyle-your-window) where the author is showing maximize button on title bar as character `#`. But I would like to show it a default button as shown below:

[image]

Currently my customized title bar looks like the following:

[image]

**Question**: How can we modify the following xaml to achieve the above? I am thinking may be we only need to modify following tag:

```
<Button x:Name="btnRestore" Click="MaximizeRestoreClick" Content="#"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
```

**MyWindowStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="WPFtest.WindowStyle"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFtest">

    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30" CornerRadius="4" GlassFrameThickness="0" NonClientFrameEdges="None" ResizeBorderThickness="5" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="5,30,5,5">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>

                        <DockPanel Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" LastChildFill="False">
                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Left" FontSize="12" Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnClose" Click="CloseClick" Content="X" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnRestore" Click="MaximizeRestoreClick" Content="#"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnMinimize" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Click="MinimizeClick"
                                    Content="_" DockPanel.Dock="Right" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
                        </DockPanel>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: As far that I am aware, there is no way to use default "windows button". You need to use some icon library. I do use https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Getting-Started where are <PackIcon /> which you can see here https://materialdesignicons.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot show the default buttons when you define a custom chrome window style, but you could easily style your custom buttons to look like the default ones.

Use the `Segoe MDL2 Assets` font family as I suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44777463/7252182):

```
<Button x:Name="btnMinimize" Content="&#xE949;"
                Padding="0 1 1 0"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                Click="MinimizeClick" DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Width="44" Height="30">
                <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                                   FontSize="10" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Auto"
                                   TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"
                                   TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Background" Value="#E5E5E5"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be for Minimize button. I'm looking for `Maximize` button. It seems some value changes in your suggested code should make it work.

Comment: @nam: For the maximize button, you should change the content to &#xE739; as per the answer I linked to. What's your current issue? You don't expect me or anyone else to provide markup for all the buttons for you, do you?

Comment: Your suggestion gave an idea for all other buttons. I made some modifications per my needs. For example, I moved the `ControlTemplate` block etc to `<DockPanel.Resources>.....</DockPanel.Resources>` block inside `DockPanel` since all the buttons are inside this panel. Since your code is using `TargetType="Button"` it worked for all buttons inside my `DockPanel`.